# If the original Facebook page owner for a business page deletes their personal account, does the page disappear even with a new owner?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

Does a Facebook Business page disappear if the original creator deletes their personal account after they gave ownership to an agency? We can't risk losing that page.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post from a Facebook Help Team member](https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10203785588198455):

> if you want to delete your business Page, you must be the current admin of the Page.

Therefore, if you are no longer the current admin, you won't be able to delete the business page -- even if you delete your account.

Also, per [Blogging Bistro](https://bloggingbistro.com/how-to-delete-a-facebook-page/), even if your business page does somehow get removed when you delete your personal page, you'll have 14 days to reactivate the page before it's deleted permanently.

Comment: This information is correct but doesn't answer to the question. OP is not asking to delete the business page.

Comment: @serenesat OP is asking about losing a business page if removing a personal page. According to the information above, if the owner of the personal page isn't an admin for the business page, losing the business page when deleting a personal page is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

**No**, Page will not disappear. If there are more than one Admin, page will not disappear. So before deleting your personal profile, make someone [Admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/187316341316631/) of the page.

To add other persons for any [role](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410?helpref=faq_content), you must be an Admin of the Page.

Note - always give an Admin role to a trusted person because Admin can remove you from the page and take your Page from you forever.